# Return the last non-zero return code in a shell script

Tags: shell, exit

I'm running a build script and want it to complete, but return a non-zero return code if something goes wrong. So far, the only way I know to do this is:

```
command1
rc1=$?

command2
rc2=$?

...

commandn
rcn=$?

exit $rc1 + $rc2 + ... + $rcn
```

Is there a better way to do this, similar to pipefail but for non-piped commands?

**Update**: I don't actually *want* the sum (nor do I think it's prudent) - just a non-zero return on error. I'm running a script where I want the build to fail if something goes wrong, but to finish the build so we may have a runnable state even if some validation check fails.

Comment: Nitpick: That won't work--you can't have spaces around the `=` sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### That's probably not what you want

You probably don't want to add error codes, since they'd become pretty meaningless. Instead, it is probably best to exit on the first error you encounter and show it.

You can do this by chaining command together with the [`&&` operator](http://linux-training.be/files/books/html/fun/ch11s04.html):

```
command1 \
&& command2 \
&& command3 \
|| echo "command failed: $?"
```

For example:

```
➤ echo show && (exit 188) && echo noshow || echo "failed: $?"
show
failed: 188
```

### If you must...

You can wrap your commands with a function that will keep track of the exit value:

```
SUM_EXIT=0

wrap() {
  eval "$@"
  SUM_EXIT=$(($SUM_EXIT+$?))
}

wrap command1
wrap command2
wrap command3

exit $SUM_EXIT
```

Note that this is (IMO) a perfectly valid use for `eval`. You will be running commands you wrote yourself. Just be careful with strange filenames and arguments that could contain newlines. Quote the command completely if you're unsure:

```
➤ wrap "(echo \"this is a 
newline containing string\" && exit 5)"
➤ echo $SUM_EXIT
5
```

Comment: your solution is not adding the return values, just giving the return value of the last command that failed. And the chain of commands will stop as soon as there's one command failing. Definitely not what the OP asks.

Comment: You're right. Are you sure you want to continue the script with a failed command?

Comment: I'm not, but that's what the OPs wants! :-)

Comment: :) I'd argue that it's probably not what he needs. I'll put together a solution that does.

Comment: +1 for noting that adding exit statuses is not what you really want.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm of the opinion that this is a perfectly valid use case for eval. Saying `eval` stands for `evil` is short sighted, especially in this context since you'de be running the commands anyway.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers There's no difference between running `command` and `eval command` in term of safety. If `command` will shoot off your foot, it will happen either way.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Using eval on user input, now that's a bad idea. But this isn't that.

Comment: I agree with @brice on the really exceptional case where `eval()` is not evil.

Comment: and I think that'd be the only alternative the OP would have to adding the results for each command, like I suggested

Comment: I think you *really* want to quote `$@` if you're sending it to `eval`. But it's still evil.

Comment: @l0b0 Agreed, should be quoted. Changed to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

If bash is an option.

To track the "cumulative" return code

```
declare -i rc=0
command1 || ((rc += $?))
command2 || ((rc += $?))
command3 || ((rc += $?))
exit $rc
```

If you need to track the number of commands that have failed and not their return codes

```
declare -i rc=0
command1 || ((++rc))
command2 || ((++rc))
command3 || ((++rc))
exit $rc
```

Comment: JFTR, that won't add up the return codes of the commands, but count how many commands have failed. Which may be useful in its own right.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, good catch! Doesn't do exactly what the OP's code does but I'll leave the solution in FWIW

Comment: @1_CR actually...how many commands have failed is probably more meaningful information!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: If you don't want to soldier on after the first command failed, you can `set -e` at the top of the script to make it exit as soon as the first command (not part of a control structure like `if cmd`) exits nonzero.

Your shell manual has all the details. My Bourne Shell says:

> ```
>  -e errexit
>          Exit immediately if any untested command fails in non-interactive
>          mode.  The exit status of a command is considered to be explic-
>          itly tested if the command is part of the list used to control an
>          if, elif, while, or until; if the command is the left hand oper-
>          and of an ``&&'' or ``||'' operator; or if the command is a pipe-
>          line preceded by the ! operator.  If a shell function is executed
>          and its exit status is explicitly tested, all commands of the
>          function are considered to be tested as well.
> ```

Comment: but that's not what the OP wants! He wants to store return values and return the addition of the return values when something went wrong, without exiting the current script.

Comment: He explicitly mentioned that he wants the script to complete, so `-e` is not an option.

Comment: @zmo And then what? So you don't know what command failed. If you care for failed commands you either stop right away or test each command separately. Adding up exit statuses is just, excuse my french, dumb, since it destroys information.

Comment: +1 Wanting a script to complete no matter what is the textbook definition of an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 0):

as you ask for a better way to do this (but I'm sure that's not the most elegant and best way), you could do that instead:

```
rc=0

command1
rc=$(($rc+=$?))

command2
rc=$(($rc+=$?))

...

commandn
rc=$(($rc+=$?))

exit $rc
```

Comment: why `rc=$(($rc+=$?))` and not `rc=$(($rc+$?))`

Comment: true. at least the POSIX shell allows you to drop the `$` inside the arithmetic expression: `rc=$((rc+$?))`

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simplified variant of the solution [zmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17308199/1630171) suggested:

```
((rc+=$?))
```

Or you could use logical operators if you're just interested in whether or not the return code is different from zero:

```
rc=$((rc || $?))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, summing up the return values is a really bad idea, because the return value is reduced with modulo 256 and the next maintainer will curse you for having to add code to figure out where it failed. That means if the sum is a multiple of 256 it will return 0 (aka. success), which is not what OP wants.

Second, you can't return anything other than a simple integer. There's no way to return an array of return values.

To make the [exit code sum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17308199/96588) solution work you therefore have to

```
if [ "${rc-0}" -lt 256 ]
then
    return ${rc-0}
else
    return 255
fi
```

That said, my +1 goes to the [`set -e`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17308174/96588) solution. It is a bad idea to simply continue processing if a command fails. If they depend on each other, you're likely to see unexpected results, and if they don't, why are they in the same script?